# Missing windows command line history when executed from Matlab

Tags: windows, matlab, command-prompt

I occasionally use the Matlab 'dos' command which brings up a command window and executes a program for me. However, I've discovered that the command issued through Matlab is not present in the history of the command window - which means that I can't simply hit the up arrow key to call up the command and run it again.

Is there a way to retrieve Windows command window history when the original command was issued through the Matlab 'dos' function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The Windows command processor only stores what you typed in the command history.  [Alternative command processors](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-command-prompt-cmd/) may differ.